# bash/mysql complains about ) character

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm trying to execute this:

```
$ mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX --batch --skip-column-names \
 -e "SELECT userid, displayname FROM Users" stackoverflowdb | \
split -l 50 -a 5 - "result."
```

but bash complains about ) 'unexpected' character (i have this character and few other 'weird ones' in my mysql password). I tried to take my password in quotes `--password="myweirdpasshere"` but then mysql won't login me at all (probably password is incorrect?)

Comment: Does it work if you "escape" the open-parens with a backslash first? e.g. "my\\(password"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't give the password on the command line, it will bring up an interactive prompt.  That might solve your error.  Just use `-p` instead of `--password=XXX`.

Of course, if you require unattended access to the script, that's not a very useful answer.  It would be more helpful if you could create a minimal example and tell us the exact error that Bash gives you.

Comment: now my hd works intensively so i guess something is happening... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some characters such as $, `, ", and sometimes \ retain their special meaning inside double quotes.  If your password contains any of those characters, use single quotes instead.  (Unless your password also contains single quotes, in which case you might just drop the quotes altogether and put a \ before each special character.)

Comment: If you've a lot of special characters, maybe use `'xxxxx'\''yyyy'`; this uses single quotes to suppress all special characters except "`'`"; the sequence "`'\''`" (excluding the double quotes) terminates the current single quoted string, adds a backslashed single quote, and starts a new single quoted string.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to put the password in the `$HOME/.my.cnf` file, avoiding this issue *as well as increasing the security*.

Another option to using `$HOME/.my.cnf` is embedding the configuration file into the script. A comment on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-security-user.html) gives examples on this. For your case it should be:

```
$ mysql --user=XXX --defaults-file <(printf '[client]\npassword=XXX\n') \
--batch --skip-column-names \
-e "SELECT userid, displayname FROM Users" stackoverflowdb | \
split -l 50 -a 5 - "result."
```

Comment: You should do one or the other, I think. It seems as though you are combining two different methods.

Comment: Good feedback. Yes, I describe two different, alternative options, but the text does not make that very obvious. I will make it clearer.